# Macro for updating value of one column in excel based on other column

Tags: vba, excel

```
SeqNo   RunStat    i_Day
1       Completed   1
2       Completed   1
3       Completed   1
4       Completed   1
5       Completed   2
6       Completed   2
7       Completed   3
8       Completed   4
9       Completed   4
10      Completed   5
11      Completed   5
12      Completed   5
13      Completed   6
14      Completed   6
```

Here we have 3 columns in excel.

We have to update `Runstat` column value to `Run` based on `i_Day` column values.
Problem is to create a macro to Update `Runstat` column value to `Run` when `i_Day = 1` for day 1 . Next day again Update `Runstat` column value to `Run` when `i_Day = 2` for day 2 and so on.  So All the `Runstat` fields with `i_Day` as `1` should get marked as `Run` and for other `Runstat`  fields with different `i_Day` values column `Runstat` should remain as `Complete`.

Please suggest best solution to this.

Comment: Please show what you have researched and tried to achieve this. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. [Edit] your question and add the code you have. Tell where you got errors and which or where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

No need OF VBA for that. Just normal formulas.

Let's say your columns are A,B,C

In column B (RunStat) use this formula:

```
=IF(C2=1;"Run";"Completed")
```

Comment: On day 1, i want to update RunStat field value to "Run" for I_Day= 1. On next dat i.e day 2,  i want to update RunStat field value to "Run" for I_Day= 2. same will continue..

Comment: the solution you provided is specific for day 1. Please suggest a generalized solution.

Comment: I answered this because you posted *All the Runstat fields with i_Day as 1 should get marked as Run and for other Runstat fields with different i_Day values column Runstat should remain as Complete*.

Comment: I appreciate.. Can you please suggest for current scenario.

Comment: When you say *day 1, day 2*, you are talking about the days yoou open the file. So you will need a date reference that can check the different between that date reference and the actual date. And then, update column Runstat where i-day is less or equal to that difference.

Comment: Now i will explain you the complete scenario. Actually i have 300 excel sheets and 10 days of execution. Now everyday i open 300 excel sheet one by one manually and update Runstat column to run based on day value. I want to automate this manual work as it is time consuming. Is there any way i can run a macro and macro can update Runstat field to "run"  based on i_Day value for all the 300 data sheets. and same continues for all days.

Comment: That's a totally different question. But yes, you can do it with VBA. Update your question with the complete scenario and all the information you have updated here. And also, post all the codes you have tried, and specify where are you stuck and what errors you get when you execute your code.